# row-by-row sorting of a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix, and I need to sort its data row by row. right now I'm just doing

```
sort(matrix,2, 'descend')
```

but I was wondering if the same operation would go faster if I transposed the matrix, did the sort on the columns and then transposed it back to its original dimensions, or if there was any other way to get better speed.

Comment: did you try timing the two operations for your case? I would say depends on the sparsity of the matrix and dimensions (row/columns). My guess is MATLAB optimizes sorting when you are specifying along dimension 1 or 2 and you shouldn't have to go with the overhead of two transpose operations. Unless, as I said before, you have prior knowledge on the structure of the matrix.

Comment: I would think that people at Matlab would have thought of transpose-sort-transpose and used it if it was actually faster. This was for full matrices. I don't know the exact internal structure of a sparse matrix, but I don't think transposing would even matter. As for speed - have you tried timing any of the two options?

Comment: yeah, I tried timing it, and in the end it's just 0.20 secs faster when done by column, which I guess amounts to nothing if then you account also the overhead for transposition. However, I discovered that the culprit for the slowdowns was actually repmat, and not sort as I thought

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

Doing the sort by column is a little faster, but the time gained is (much) less than the time used to transpose the matrix twice.

There is probably no general way to speed this up, but when you have more knowledge about the specific matrix structure there may be a way.